# plotting a linear classifier output

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried writing a small code of linear classifier without using any API to understand the linear classifier logic.
My code is below:

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    
    # Generate a random dataset with 2 features and two classes

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.randn(100,2)
y = np.concatenate([np.ones(50), -1*np.ones(50)])


# Generate a random test set with the same number of features

    X_test = np.random.randn(50,2)
    y_test = np.concatenate([np.ones(25), -1*np.ones(25)])
    
    
    
    # Define a function to train a linear classifier on the data
    
    def linear_classifier(X, y, learning_rate=0.01, num_epochs=100):
        num_features = X.shape[1] 
        weights = np.zeros(num_features)
        bias = 0
        
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            for i in range(X.shape[0]):
                linear_output = np.dot(X[i], weights) + bias
               
                y_pred = np.sign(linear_output)
                
               
                error = y[i] - y_pred
                # print("The value of error=", error)
                weights = weights + learning_rate * error * X[i]
    
                bias += learning_rate * error
                
        return weights, bias
    
    
    # Train the linear classifier on the training set 
    weights, bias = linear_classifier(X, y) 
    
    # Apply the learned weights and bias to the test set
    linear_output = np.dot(X_test, weights) + bias
    
    
    y_pred = np.sign(linear_output)
    
    # Compute the accuracy of the classifier on the test set
    accuracy = np.mean(y_pred == y_test)
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy)
```

I saw at various links that for plotting a two dimensional data, they use a function called as scatter plot. Can any one guide me how to use the scatter plot.
I tried using this statement as below but I could not make it work.

```
# Plot the data points with different colors for different classes
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], y)
```

Can anyone guide me how to plot the linear classifier features with a hyperplane.

**Edit**
The error I am getting is :

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[77], line 2
      1 # Plot the data points with different colors for different classes
----> 2 plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], y)
```

Comment: Thank you @Hermann12 for the response. I have edited the question with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide y as a parameter for "c"

> `plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], c=y)`

In addition, You either need to re-define "x" to "X", or change the "X" to "x" in your code.

[Here's the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQf0s.jpg)

Comment: Thank you @Strikoder for the response. I would be great if you can explain what is x and and y axis and what exactly is y in this plot and how to plot the hyperplane?

Comment: The x-axis represents the values of the first feature, and the y-axis represents the values of the second feature.

Comment: @Deepika The data is colored based on the class labels. In our case, there were two classes: class 1 and class -1. The blue points represent class 1, and the orange ones represent class -1. This means that each observation in the dataset belongs to one of these two classes.

Comment: Thank you @Strikoder for the response. So, color means class 1 and class -1. But how you  decide which color means which class?

Comment: plt.scatter maps the color blue to the number 1 and the color orange to the number -1. Nevertheless, you can change the color mapping by specifying the color sequence to the c parameter explicitly.
`desired_colors = ['r' if label == 1 else 'g' for label in y]`
`plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=desired_colors )`